# Periodic version is constant implies f is constant

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence, fourier-analysis

Let $f:\mathbb R\to \mathbb R$ be a uniformly continuous function with finite measure support.

Let $g$ be the periodic version of $f$ defined on [0,1), that is:
$$
g(x)=\sum_{k\in \mathbb Z}f(x+k)
$$
Then we can show that $g$ converges pointwisely.
Now my question is: if $g$ is identically zero, does it imply that $f$ is so?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: May I ask how you define $\sum_{k\in\Bbb Z}$? Is it just the limit of $\sum_{k=i}^j$ as $i\rightarrow-\infty,j\rightarrow\infty$?

Comment: By virtue of the condition of finite measure support, we can show that for almost all x, this is a finite sum. So it does not matter indeed. Thank you for your comment.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the function $f(t)=\sin(\pi t)I_{[0,2)}$, where $I_A$ is the indicator function of the set $A$. Then $f$ is continuous and compactly supported in $\mathbb{R}$, is not identically zero, but $g\equiv 0$.